# how calculate rectangle size for d3.js heatmap

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to create a heat map using d3. I have created the axis and scale but I am stuck on how to draw rectangles. I get the x and y points from the rectangle using the built in scale function e.g

```
attr('x', d => {
    return timeScale(d.hour);
  })
  .attr('y', d => {
    return dayScale(d.day);
  })
```

But the problem is in calculating the width and height of each rectangle. I do not know how to calculate it. So far I am using

```
 .attr('width', gridSize)
 .attr('height', gridSize)
```

to set the height and width but it is not working correctly. I know another method would be to use:

```
  .attr('x', d => (((d.hour - 1) * gridSize) + padding))
  .attr('y', d => (((d.day - 1) * gridSize) + padding))
  .attr('class', 'hour bordered')
  .attr('width', gridSize)
  .attr('height', gridSize)
  .style('fill', colors[0])
```

but want to avoid this.

You can find the code which I have written/copied so far [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XBRJxG?editors=1010)

```
var margin = {
  top: 80,
  right: 30,
  bottom: 10,
  left: 30
};

//Width and height
var width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
var padding = 49;

gridSize = Math.floor((width - (padding * 2)) / 24) // size of individual gridItem i.e the square which is drawn
/*
  To calculate the gridSize we take width and subtract padding * 2, why times 2 because padding is on both side of the square (the gridItem). Then we divide 
  it by 24
*/
buckets = 12;
legendElementWidth = gridSize * 2
colors = ["#FFCB4A", "#D7C74A", "#C5C54A", "#B3C34A", "#A0C149", "#8EBF49", "#7CBE49", "#6ABC49", "#58BA49", "#45B848", "#33B648", "#21B448"]
days = ["Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa", "Su"]
times = ["1a", "2a", "3a", "4a", "5a", "6a", "7a", "8a", "9a", "10a", "11a", "12a", "1p", "2p", "3p", "4p", "5p", "6p", "7p", "8p", "9p", "10p", "11p", "12p"]

colorScale = d3.scaleQuantile().domain([0, buckets - 1, d3.max(dataset, d => d.value)]).range(colors); // no idea what is buckets - 1 doing here :(

var svg = d3.select('.card')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`)


var dayScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([7, 1]).range([height, 0]);

var dayAxis = d3.axisLeft().ticks(7).scale(dayScale)
svg.append('g').attr('class', 'xAxis').call(dayAxis)

var timeScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([1, 24]).range([0, width])
var timeAxis = d3.axisTop().scale(timeScale).ticks(24)
svg.append('g').attr('class', 'yAxis').call(timeAxis)


svg.selectAll('.squares')
  .data(dataset)
  .enter()
  .append('rect')
  .attr('x', d => {
    return timeScale(d.hour);
  })
  .attr('y', d => {
    return dayScale(d.day);
  })
  .attr('width', gridSize)
  .attr('height', gridSize)
  .style('fill', d => colorScale(d.value))
dataset = [{
        day: 1,
        hour: 1,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 1,
        hour: 2,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 1,
        hour: 3,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 1,
        hour: 4,
        value: 1
      },
      {
        day: 1,
        hour: 5,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 1,
        hour: 6,
        value: 1
      },
      {
        day: 1,
        hour: 7,
        value: 2
      },
      {
        day: 1,
        hour: 8,
        value: 2
      },
      {
        day: 1,
        hour: 9,
        value: 3
      },
      {
        day: 1,
        hour: 10,
        value: 5
      },
      {
        day: 1,
        hour: 11,
        value: 14
      },
      {
        day: 1,
        hour: 12,
        value: 8
      },
      {
        day: 1,
        hour: 13,
        value: 16
      },
      {
        day: 1,
        hour: 14,
        value: 20
      },
      {
        day: 1,
        hour: 15,
        value: 7
      },
      {
        day: 1,
        hour: 16,
        value: 11
      },
      {
        day: 1,
        hour: 17,
        value: 10
      },
      {
        day: 1,
        hour: 18,
        value: 4
      },
      {
        day: 1,
        hour: 19,
        value: 7
      },
      {
        day: 1,
        hour: 20,
        value: 4
      },
      {
        day: 1,
        hour: 21,
        value: 1
      },
      {
        day: 1,
        hour: 22,
        value: 2
      },
      {
        day: 1,
        hour: 23,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 1,
        hour: 24,
        value: 1
      },
      {
        day: 2,
        hour: 1,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 2,
        hour: 2,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 2,
        hour: 3,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 2,
        hour: 4,
        value: 1
      },
      {
        day: 2,
        hour: 5,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 2,
        hour: 6,
        value: 2
      },
      {
        day: 2,
        hour: 7,
        value: 4
      },
      {
        day: 2,
        hour: 8,
        value: 6
      },
      {
        day: 2,
        hour: 9,
        value: 2
      },
      {
        day: 2,
        hour: 10,
        value: 12
      },
      {
        day: 2,
        hour: 11,
        value: 15
      },
      {
        day: 2,
        hour: 12,
        value: 18
      },
      {
        day: 2,
        hour: 13,
        value: 11
      },
      {
        day: 2,
        hour: 14,
        value: 24
      },
      {
        day: 2,
        hour: 15,
        value: 6
      },
      {
        day: 2,
        hour: 16,
        value: 10
      },
      {
        day: 2,
        hour: 17,
        value: 14
      },
      {
        day: 2,
        hour: 18,
        value: 3
      },
      {
        day: 2,
        hour: 19,
        value: 1
      },
      {
        day: 2,
        hour: 20,
        value: 2
      },
      {
        day: 2,
        hour: 21,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 2,
        hour: 22,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 2,
        hour: 23,
        value: 1
      },
      {
        day: 2,
        hour: 24,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 3,
        hour: 1,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 3,
        hour: 2,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 3,
        hour: 3,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 3,
        hour: 4,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 3,
        hour: 5,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 3,
        hour: 6,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 3,
        hour: 7,
        value: 1
      },
      {
        day: 3,
        hour: 8,
        value: 1
      },
      {
        day: 3,
        hour: 9,
        value: 3
      },
      {
        day: 3,
        hour: 10,
        value: 6
      },
      {
        day: 3,
        hour: 11,
        value: 11
      },
      {
        day: 3,
        hour: 12,
        value: 15
      },
      {
        day: 3,
        hour: 13,
        value: 10
      },
      {
        day: 3,
        hour: 14,
        value: 6
      },
      {
        day: 3,
        hour: 15,
        value: 2
      },
      {
        day: 3,
        hour: 16,
        value: 7
      },
      {
        day: 3,
        hour: 17,
        value: 9
      },
      {
        day: 3,
        hour: 18,
        value: 13
      },
      {
        day: 3,
        hour: 19,
        value: 11
      },
      {
        day: 3,
        hour: 20,
        value: 8
      },
      {
        day: 3,
        hour: 21,
        value: 4
      },
      {
        day: 3,
        hour: 22,
        value: 1
      },
      {
        day: 3,
        hour: 23,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 3,
        hour: 24,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 4,
        hour: 1,
        value: 1
      },
      {
        day: 4,
        hour: 2,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 4,
        hour: 3,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 4,
        hour: 4,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 4,
        hour: 5,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 4,
        hour: 6,
        value: 1
      },
      {
        day: 4,
        hour: 7,
        value: 2
      },
      {
        day: 4,
        hour: 8,
        value: 4
      },
      {
        day: 4,
        hour: 9,
        value: 7
      },
      {
        day: 4,
        hour: 10,
        value: 4
      },
      {
        day: 4,
        hour: 11,
        value: 2
      },
      {
        day: 4,
        hour: 12,
        value: 1
      },
      {
        day: 4,
        hour: 13,
        value: 5
      },
      {
        day: 4,
        hour: 14,
        value: 8
      },
      {
        day: 4,
        hour: 15,
        value: 10
      },
      {
        day: 4,
        hour: 16,
        value: 14
      },
      {
        day: 4,
        hour: 17,
        value: 8
      },
      {
        day: 4,
        hour: 18,
        value: 4
      },
      {
        day: 4,
        hour: 19,
        value: 3
      },
      {
        day: 4,
        hour: 20,
        value: 1
      },
      {
        day: 4,
        hour: 21,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 4,
        hour: 22,
        value: 2
      },
      {
        day: 4,
        hour: 23,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 4,
        hour: 24,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 5,
        hour: 1,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 5,
        hour: 2,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 5,
        hour: 3,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 5,
        hour: 4,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 5,
        hour: 5,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 5,
        hour: 6,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 5,
        hour: 7,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 5,
        hour: 8,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 5,
        hour: 9,
        value: 3
      },
      {
        day: 5,
        hour: 10,
        value: 1
      },
      {
        day: 5,
        hour: 11,
        value: 5
      },
      {
        day: 5,
        hour: 12,
        value: 10
      },
      {
        day: 5,
        hour: 13,
        value: 14
      },
      {
        day: 5,
        hour: 14,
        value: 17
      },
      {
        day: 5,
        hour: 15,
        value: 23
      },
      {
        day: 5,
        hour: 16,
        value: 10
      },
      {
        day: 5,
        hour: 17,
        value: 8
      },
      {
        day: 5,
        hour: 18,
        value: 5
      },
      {
        day: 5,
        hour: 19,
        value: 3
      },
      {
        day: 5,
        hour: 20,
        value: 1
      },
      {
        day: 5,
        hour: 21,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 5,
        hour: 22,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 5,
        hour: 23,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 5,
        hour: 24,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 6,
        hour: 1,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 6,
        hour: 2,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 6,
        hour: 3,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 6,
        hour: 4,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 6,
        hour: 5,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 6,
        hour: 6,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 6,
        hour: 7,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 6,
        hour: 8,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 6,
        hour: 9,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 6,
        hour: 10,
        value: 1
      },
      {
        day: 6,
        hour: 11,
        value: 3
      },
      {
        day: 6,
        hour: 12,
        value: 2
      },
      {
        day: 6,
        hour: 13,
        value: 1
      },
      {
        day: 6,
        hour: 14,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 6,
        hour: 15,
        value: 2
      },
      {
        day: 6,
        hour: 16,
        value: 1
      },
      {
        day: 6,
        hour: 17,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 6,
        hour: 18,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 6,
        hour: 19,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 6,
        hour: 20,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 6,
        hour: 21,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 6,
        hour: 22,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 6,
        hour: 23,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 6,
        hour: 24,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 7,
        hour: 1,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 7,
        hour: 2,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 7,
        hour: 3,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 7,
        hour: 4,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 7,
        hour: 5,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 7,
        hour: 6,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 7,
        hour: 7,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 7,
        hour: 8,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 7,
        hour: 9,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 7,
        hour: 10,
        value: 1
      },
      {
        day: 7,
        hour: 11,
        value: 2
      },
      {
        day: 7,
        hour: 12,
        value: 4
      },
      {
        day: 7,
        hour: 13,
        value: 1
      },
      {
        day: 7,
        hour: 14,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 7,
        hour: 15,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 7,
        hour: 16,
        value: 1
      },
      {
        day: 7,
        hour: 17,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 7,
        hour: 18,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 7,
        hour: 19,
        value: 1
      },
      {
        day: 7,
        hour: 20,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 7,
        hour: 21,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 7,
        hour: 22,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 7,
        hour: 23,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        day: 7,
        hour: 24,
        value: 0
      },
    ]
```

Comment: You can try using the axes `tickSize()` property to define the width/height of your tiles.

Comment: i would use d3.scaleBand, which will give you scale.bandwidth() for your width and height of your rects, and padding too.

Comment: eg https://codepen.io/tomshanley/pen/ejWzYZ?editors=0010#0

Comment: @TomShanley perfect!! thats exactly what i was looking for. Thanks a lot. Can you post this as an answer.

Comment: @RyanMorton i tried using `tickSize()` but not looking good. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qymKdE?editors=0011

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use d3.scaleBand(), then you will be able set padding within the scale itself, and then access scale.bandwidth for the width and height of the bars.

As the scale is an 'ordinal' scale, you need to provide each category (eg day number) in the domain.

See link for an example:

https://codepen.io/tomshanley/pen/ejWzYZ?editors=0010#0

The relevant parts of the code are:

```
var dayScale = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(d3.range(7,0,-1))
  .range([height, 0])
  .padding(0.4);

var dayAxis = d3.axisLeft().ticks(7).scale(dayScale)
svg.append('g').attr('class', 'xAxis').call(dayAxis)

var timeScale = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(d3.range(1,25,1))
  .range([0, width])
  .padding(0.1)

var timeAxis = d3.axisTop().scale(timeScale).ticks(24)
svg.append('g').attr('class', 'yAxis').call(timeAxis)

svg.selectAll('.squares')
  .data(dataset)
  .enter()
  .append('rect')
  .attr('x', d => {
    return timeScale(d.hour);
  })
  .attr('y', d => {
    return dayScale(d.day);
  })
  .attr('width', timeScale.bandwidth())
  .attr('height', dayScale.bandwidth())
  .style('fill', d => colorScale(d.value))
```